# How to read XML Response CSV Data in Java

Tags: java

I have data something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
"product_code","description","brand_Code","price","start_date","end_date","earliest_shipping_date","status","available_indicator"
"139005L","Cheryl's Crunchy Tree Cookies - Caseof 48","1001","74.9100","2013-12-03","2021-12-31","2013-12-05","A","Y"
"139057","Cheryl's Get Well Cookie Cards - Case of 25","1001","40.6300","2014-01-10","2021-12-31","2014-01-20","A","N"
</response>
```

I need to read this data and insert into table as rows.
How can I read such data in Java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the XML and extract the text content of the *<response>* tag. That text content is essentially the content of a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. According to the sample XML in your question, I'm assuming that you want to skip the first line and split each of the remaining lines into individual values. The following code demonstrates how to do this. Note that I copied the XML data from your question to a file which I named *response.xml*.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new File("response.xml"));
            NodeList responses = doc.getElementsByTagName("response");
            int count = responses.getLength();
            String verb = count == 1 ? "is" : "are";
            String plural = count == 1 ? "" : "s";
            System.out.printf("There %s %d response%s.%n", verb, count, plural);
            Node response = responses.item(0);
            String content = response.getTextContent();
            String[] lines = content.split("\n");
            count = lines.length;
            verb = count == 1 ? "is" : "are";
            plural = count == 1 ? "" : "s";
            System.out.printf("There %s %d line%s.%n", verb, count, plural);
            for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
                String[] columns = lines[i].split(",");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I got when I ran the above code.

```
There is 1 response.
There are 4 lines.
["139005L", "Cheryl's Crunchy Tree Cookies - Caseof 48", "1001", "74.9100", "2013-12-03", "2021-12-31", "2013-12-05", "A", "Y"]
["139057", "Cheryl's Get Well Cookie Cards - Case of 25", "1001", "40.6300", "2014-01-10", "2021-12-31", "2014-01-20", "A", "N"]
```

Note that I did not want to guess what you mean by...

> insert into table as rows

Do you mean database tables?

There are many online tutorials explaining how to parse XML with java code, including [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) which is one of the trails in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend something like [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) rather than rolling your own CSV parser.  This one, for example, doesn't handle escaped quotes.